# Mostrando barra de rolagem sozinho com elemento textarea

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap

Segue JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7vaf1th8/15/

Está mostrando barra de rolagem horizontal no textarea.

Segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma solução ?

Comment: No Fiddle está normal.

Comment: Aumentei, diminui e nada apareceu :/

Comment: Aqui não aparece esse scroll.

Comment: De qualquer forma vc pode forçar colocando o CSS `overflow-x: hidden;` no textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dito nos comentários, o problema não pôde ser percebido em testes locais, porém, uma solução é atribuir o estilo `overflow-x: hidden;` ao `textarea` para prevenir tal problema.

**Direto *inline*:**

```
<textarea style="overflow-x: hidden;"></textarea>
```

**Ou no CSS:**

```
textarea{
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```